# Extracting word after fixed word with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file `file.txt` containing a very long line:

```
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-962797807950|mar0101|0|00000106829DAE7F3FAB187550B920530C00|0|0|4000018001000002||962797807950|||||-1|||||-1||-1|0||||0||||||-1|-1|||-1|0|-1|-1|-1|2012.12.01 00:08:35|1|0||-1|1|||||||||||||0|0|||472|0|12|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||1|6|252|tid{111211344662580792}pfid{10}gob{1}rid{globitel} afid{}uid1{962797807950}aid1{1}ar1{100}uid2{globitel}aid2{-1}pid{1234}pur{!GDRC RESERVE AMOUNT 10000}ratinf{}rec{0}rots{0}tda{}mid{}exd{0}reqa{100}ctr{StaffLine}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{PayCall Ticket}||
```

I want to print only the word after "ctr" in this file, which is "StaffLine", 
and I don't how many characters there are in this word.

I've tried:

```
awk '{comp[substr("ctr",0)]{print}}'
```

but it didn't work.  How can I get hold of that word?

Comment: You've written "thanks; didn't work" or thereabouts to four answers.  That's very odd; all four answers work for me.  That suggests there's a problem at your end.  What system are you using (you said 'Unix', but that covers a lot of territory)?  Which shell are you using?  What is the error message when any given answer fails?  Did you try the answers on the text copied from the question, or did you try it on the text you copied into the question?  We've only got what was copied into the question to work with, of course.

Comment: Is this a GWT servlet response? :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F "[{}]" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "ctr") print $(i+1) }' file
```

Or if your version of `grep` supports Perl-like regex:

```
grep -oP "(?<=ctr{)[^}]+" file
```

Results:

```
StaffLine
```

Comment: @eyadgh: What error message did you receive? Is your system broken? What versions of `awk` and `sed` are you using? The other answers here should all work too. Also, what is your environment?

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/.*}ctr{\([^}]*\).*/\1/' input
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of dealing with it is with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/.*}ctr{//; s/}.*//' file.txt
```

This deletes everything up to and including the `{` after the word `ctr` (avoiding issues with any words which have `ctr` as a suffix, such as a hypothetical `pxctr{Bogus}` entry); it then deletes anything from the first remaining `}` onwards, leaving just `StaffLine` on the sample data.

Comment: Curious: in what way did it not work for you?  Given the sample data row copied from the question and the sample sed script copied from the answer, I got the output StaffLine which was what I understood was required.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '$_=m/.*ctr{([^}]*)}.*/;print $1' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-962797807950|mar0101|0|00000106829DAE7F3FAB187550B920530C00|0|0|4000018001000002||962797807950|||||-1|||||-1||-1|0||||0||||||-1|-1|||-1|0|-1|-1|-1|2012.12.01 00:08:35|1|0||-1|1|||||||||||||0|0|||472|0|12|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||1|6|252|tid{111211344662580792}pfid{10}gob{1}rid{globitel} afid{}uid1{962797807950}aid1{1}ar1{100}uid2{globitel}aid2{-1}pid{1234}pur{!GDRC RESERVE AMOUNT 10000}ratinf{}rec{0}rots{0}tda{}mid{}exd{0}reqa{100}ctr{StaffLine}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{PayCall Ticket}||
> perl -lne '$_=m/.*ctr{([^}]*)}.*/;print $1' temp
StaffLine
>
```

Comment: @eyadgh: Try `perl` instead of `per1`. You will need to install [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) first...

Comment: are you sure your are using `perl` and not `per1`.you have written numeric one instead of alphabet l in the word perl!

Comment: You could omit both `.*` patterns from your regex without affecting the result.  You might use `\bctr` to ensure that `ctr` is a word on its own.  But what you've got should work.

Comment: OP was specific asking for an `awk` solution